# After that I have vacation for a month

Tags: future-tense

Why isn't a Future Simple ("After that I **will** have vacation for a month") used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We often use the simple present tense for things scheduled in the future, such as

> I leave for France tomorrow

Reference: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/talking-about-the-future

Answer (score 0):

It's "I have" as in "I have on my schedule".

It's an idiomatic usage, and basically says "This is what I have in front of me."

"I have a vacation (for a month) approaching in my future."

Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, i get it, I asked specifically about the tenses. But thank you anyway!

Comment: There is nothing *wrong* as such with "After that I will have vacation for a month" (except it would probably be worded "After that I will have *a* vacation for a month" or "After that I will *be on* vacation for a month" or "After that I will have a month's vacation") -- it's just not what would normally be said. The idiomatic non-future-tense "I have" is far more likely to be used.